# Is there a way to programmatically overlay text on a template image and create an output image file (PNG or JPEG)?

Tags: c#, node.js, image-processing

I am creating an interactive program that takes user inputs, queries backend system and returns the output to the user. I want this output to be displayed as an image.

I have a template image that has placeholders in place. I want to replace these placeholders with actual user information text from the backend systems and present it to the user as an image (PNG,JPG).

Is there an API that does this? Even a c# or NodeJS code will suffice at this point

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at the System.Drawing namespace in C#?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you're in Windows Forms you can draw text into any graphics context using the Graphics.DrawString method in the System.Drawing namespace.  Full control over font, location, brush, etc is available with this powerful method.  [Microsoft Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring(v=vs.110).aspx)  Here is some example code:

```
public void DrawStringPointF(PaintEventArgs e)
{

    // Create string to draw.
    String drawString = "Sample Text";

    // Create font and brush.
    Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 16);
    SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

    // Create point for upper-left corner of drawing.
    PointF drawPoint = new PointF(150.0F, 150.0F);

    // Draw string to screen.
    e.Graphics.DrawString(drawString, drawFont, drawBrush, drawPoint);
}
```

Comment: The code is okay, but I don't see how you'd go from an image file to `PaintEventArgs`. Should just use `using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image)) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

For sure. You can use GraphicsMagick for this from nodejs: http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/
Here is example of command:

```
gm convert -font helvetica -fill blue -pointsize 36 -draw "text 15,50 'hello'" source.jpg destination.jpg
```

taken from here:
https://gist.github.com/wellsie/9bcfeb9f2b3869e5e555c926e4f2c0e2